# How can I copy the signature of a method to another method?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a library that has this class:

```
class Dog {
  public run(speed: number, movement: number): void;
  public run(speed: number, type: string): void;
  public run(speed: number, opts: string | number): void {
    // perform some stuff
  }
}
```

I want to create another interface with a different method name but with the same method signature as `Dog.run`. I have tried this but it doesn't work because I cannot refer to the `run` method in `Dog` by using `Dog.run`:

```
interface SpecialDog {
   runWithSpecialPower: (...args: Parameters<Dog.run>) => ReturnType<Dog.run>
}
```

In this case, I can't extend `SpecialDog` from `Dog` too because I want the method name to be `runWithSpecialPower` instead of just `run`. Is there a way I can copy the method signature of another method?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNaAHArgIxAEthoAnHAOwAoIsBTOgEwC5oKcBbPO0gGmg7wAbnQ50KAF1bsuPAJSsh8QowDcGbPiIly1WgxZtO3PtAkBPeqwgTShCogXQlK9ZlwFiZSjXpNpxjz88FgSENa29sgAPkaypE4ujKgamAD0adg8AGbwpBzQEPBihRI42dkaAL5oNWj2EjlgwHTQAMr0wIRgIAjI6JjeFADqhBIAFh10XT0ACvAA7jysVAB062CkiOHQs5tgYo2kEAA8fau6AHxy0AC8l9AASnRlpBQAKpZ0Z0gXlJe1IA)

Comment: Bracket notation instead of dot notation would be a start: `['run']` instead of `.run`, but the problem that remains is that the `run` is detected to be `(speed: number): void`, not overloaded with `(speed: number, type?: string): void`

Comment: Please consider describing the problem in more detail than "it doesn't work", so as to make your code a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also note that the playground link is corrupted.  Also also note the implementation signature `run(speed: number, type?: string): void` is [inaccessible to callers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature), so if you're trying to make two overload signatures, that's not what you're doing.

Comment: So is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbkQdW) what you're looking for?  It's hard to tell because that unusable `type?: string` parameter is confusing me.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks! I think that's probably what I'm looking for, that's to make a reference to the type of a method on another class. Thank you!

Comment: @jcalz Oh yes, I think that could be what I might be looking for. I have also updated the my TS playground link and example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you're probably just looking for [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  If you have an object `foo` of type `Foo` with a key named `"bar"`, then the type of `foo.bar` is `Foo["bar"]`, using the bracket notation.  (You can't look up property types with dot notation, as it conflicts with namespace/module exports, see [microsoft/TypeScript#30815](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30815).)  In your case, you want `Dog["run"]`:

```
interface SpecialDog {
  runWithSpecialPower: Dog["run"];
}
```

And let's verify that it works:

```
declare const specialDog: SpecialDog;
specialDog.runWithSpecialPower(1, 2);
specialDog.runWithSpecialPower(1, "okay");
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNaAHArgIxAEthoAnHAOwAoIsBTOgEwC5oKcBbPO0gGmg7wAbnQ50KAF1bsuPAJSsh8QowDcGbPiIly1WgxZtO3PtAkBPeqwgTShCogXQlK9ZlwFiZSjXpNpxjz88FgSENa29sgAPkaypE4ujKgamAD0adg8AGbwpBzQEPBihRI42dkaAL5oNWj2EjlgwHTQAMr0wIRgIAjI6Ji6AOqEEgAWHXRdPQAK8ADuPKx9ANoARLprALrqdYxT4KStwPAUNoWd3b1IrJPT14jq+vd9AHTDoxOXsws8VACM-AATHInt8Hu9KCNxncrnNFqQAfw1vAANZgcxrUFAA)